# opencv : Unable to read upper case letters through waitKey

Tags: c++, opencv, ubuntu

I have a simple switch case as follows inside an infinite while loop, to call functions based on the key pressed by the user. I am programming in C++ using opencv libraries.
The waitKey function used below is able to read the lower case letters i press on the keyboard. I am however unable to read any upper case letters and it still reads and interprets it as the corresponding lower case letter.
Any help in this regard is appreciated. should i be updating my opencv libraries? I installed opencv on ubuntu with the help of [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/334158/installing-opencv) post

os UBUNTU 13.10
opencv version 2.4.8

Pseudo code

```
while(1)
{`
    char k = waitKey(0);
    switch(k) {
        case 'a' : ... break;
        case 'b' : ... break;
        case 'A' : ... break; // UNABLE TO READ A here.
    }
}
```

Comment: For the record: this _could_ be related to the graphics library used: I used to use Gtk on 2.4.3 and no doubt, `waitKey()` did make the difference. I just switched to 2.4.10 and build it with Qt support: suddenly I discover that it doesn't make the difference between upper case and lower case !

Answer (score 1):

I found a small hint related to your problem on OpenCV forum incase you have not found it yet:  http://answers.opencv.org/question/4266/cvwaitkey-upper-lowercase-difference/

Comment: sorry for the downvote, but please *don't* suggest using the deprecated c-api to anyone.

Comment: yup. Upvote for you and corrected the answer. Thanks for pointing out. Never realized this. Just for the future read for the answer seekers: OpenCV wil drop C-API - http://answers.opencv.org/question/17546/opencv-will-drop-c-api-support-soon/

Comment: Thanks for the efforts @Ankit and berak :) i did find the post Ankit pointed out in his answer, but i just wanted to be sure, before i tried compiling the source code myself or something like that. I just checked in the index of the APIs and found that waitKey is still a C++ API and i guess there is no much of a change in that. Not sure still why it is not working. Will give it a try again.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem (with opencv-4.x). 
I think this is due to the fact that I compiled opencv with the cmake option `-D WITH_QT=ON` (to enable the zoom scroll on images). But Qt interprets q and Q as the same keycode (81); the only thing is that it adds a (shift) modifier.

Let's say you receive a `QKeyEvent` event in a C++/Qt program. Then you get when pressing:

- 'Q': event.key() = 81, event.modifiers().testFlag(Qt::KeyboardModifier::ShiftModifier) = true
- 'q': event.key() = 81, event.modifiers().testFlag(Qt::KeyboardModifier::ShiftModifier) = false

It seems `cv::waitKey` or `cv::waitKeyEx`, when opencv uses Qt, does not read the modifiers, just the key code, unfortunately...

So far, the only option I found is to **recompile with `-D WITH_QT=OFF`**. Then I can discriminate between Q and q (but also left arrow and Shifted left arrow and so on). But the trade-off is that I can't scroll the images anymore...