# Getting upper case keyboard entries from OpenCV HighGUI in Linux Environment and Python?

Tags: python, opencv

I'm currently working on a project that involves OpenCV HighGUI for reading and displaying images in a Linux environment. I need to be able to capture keyboard entries, including upper case letters, from the user while running the HighGUI window.

As an example, I like to get ASCII of 'A'(i.e 65) but I always get ASCII of 'a'(i.e 97)

I've tried using the cv::waitKey() function, which returns the ASCII code of the pressed key but I was not able to get  with caps lock or shift. Here is my code.

```
import cv2

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # Create a HighGUI window
    cv2.namedWindow("image")

    while True:
        # Display an image in the HighGUI window
        img = cv2.imread("images/histogram.png")
        cv2.imshow("image", img)

        # Wait for a key event
        key = cv2.waitKey(0)

        # Check if the key is the ESC key
        if key == 27:
            break

        # Check if the key is an upper case letter
        if key >= ord("A") and key <= ord("Z"):
            print(f"Upper case letter '{chr(key)}' pressed!")
        else:
            print(f"No upper case detected. ASCII: '{key}'")

    # Destroy the HighGUI window
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

And here is a sample output:

```
No upper case detected. ASCII: '97' # 'a'
No upper case detected. ASCII: '225' # Left Shift
No upper case detected. ASCII: '97' # 'a'
No upper case detected. ASCII: '229' # Caps
No upper case detected. ASCII: '97' # 'a'
```

Comment: Similar but very old posts exist. I was suggested to open a new post. Please refer to: 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58781653/how-can-i-get-upper-case-at-the-cv2-wait-key

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21816401/opencv-unable-to-read-upper-case-letters-through-waitkey